# If a function depends on another function, how can I assign a variable to the end product?

Tags: rust

```
fn add(x: i32, y: i32) -> fn() {
    let z = x + y;
    mul(z, 2);
}

fn mul(x1: i32, y1: i32) -> fn() {
    let z1 = x1 * y1;
    sub(z1, 2);
}

fn sub(x2: i32, y2: i32) -> (i32) {
    let z2 = x2 - y2;
    z2
}

fn main() {
    let R = add(2, 2);
    println!("{}", R);
}
```

Assigning `R` to `add(2, 2)` doesn't work. I need to be able to assign `R` from add -> mul -> sub which returns z2.

So, the process is `add(2, 2)` -> `mul(4, 2)` -> `sub(8, 2)` thus getting R = 6. How do I go about doing this?

This is the error I get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(i32): std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
   --> testzz.rs:20:16
   |
20 | println!("{}", R);
   |                ^ the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for 
    `fn(i32)`
   |
 = note: `fn(i32)` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using 
`:?` instead if you are using a format string
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

Comment: I apologize for the formatting

Comment: Oh i forgot to add the error message. I just added it now.

Comment: What type does `sub` return? What about `add`? How do you know the answer to this? How does the compiler?

Comment: well sub will return i32 which i wrote, but I guess the first step, add needs to return a function because its last line is mul(), and sub needs to return a function too since its last line is sub()

Comment: Shepmaster, thank you for the help. My Rust assignment is now complete and our course is now moving onto Elixir. Time to bother the people over at Elixir, and after them, Haskell. Brace yourselves

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you are confused about the syntax of return types of functions. The code compiles perfectly after a couple of minor edits:

```
fn add(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    let z = x + y;
    mul(z, 2)
}

fn mul(x1: i32, y1: i32) -> i32 {
    let z1 = x1 * y1;
    sub(z1, 2)
}

fn sub(x2: i32, y2: i32) -> i32 {
    let z2 = x2 - y2;
    z2
}
```

Note that the return type of all functions is now `i32`. Returning `fn()` means something completely different and doesn't make sense in this case. Also, I removed the semicolons at the end of `add` and `mul` so Rust knows that they are the return values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is, is it possible to assign a variable like so:

let sum = add(2,2) and get 6? In other words, can I get sum = z2. I get a mismatched type error which expects fn() -> i32

Comment: Maybe you are forgetting a `;` after `let sum = add(2,2)`?